# Kio estas "Politkleriga Fako" kaj "Ĉefpolitkleriga Fako"?

Tags: word-meaning

Ŝajne ĝi estas iu organo en Soveta Registaro. 
Mi trovis la terminon en la libro *la Danĝera lingvo*.

Answer (score 3):

Verŝajne tio aludas malprecize iun **sekcion de la Ministerio de Edukado**, en la frua Sovetunio. La *politkleriga fako* estas *fako kies tasko estas la klerigado de la popolo*.

---

La mallongigita nomo de la ministerio estis *Narkom**pros*** (ruse: Наркомпрос). La *-pros* devenas de la vorto *prosveŝĉenija* (ruse: просвещения). Tiu vorto signifas *edukadon*, sed ankaŭ *klerigadon*. Do, kelkaj tradukoj de *Narkompros* uzas la vorton *kleriga* anstataŭ *eduka*.

En la angla, ni uzas *education* ankaŭ por plenkreskuloj (ni neniam uzas *enlightenment* por ĉiutagaj aferoj), sed aliaj lingvoj preferas fari distingon, kaj tio fojfoje aperas en Esperanto kiel *eduki* kontraŭ *klerigi*.

La vorto *polito* estas tre malofta termino, laŭŝajne uzita kiel varianto de *politiko* sed sen firma signifo. En ĉi tiu kunteksto ĝi verŝajne signifas *la popolon*.

Answer (score 0):

Mi ne scias la vorto *polito*. Eble ĝi estu *politiko*.

> politiko = Scienco aŭ arto rilata al la regado de regno
>
> klerigi = Instrui iun pri kulture utilaj temoj
>
> fako = Aparta dividaĵo de meblo, kesto aŭ objekto, destinita por enteni aĵojn aŭ personojn, apartigante ilin

El la ReVo

Comment: Rimarku, ke la vorto en la demando ne estas *politik*kleriga, sed *polit*kleriga